# update query with changing variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables

I am trying to populate a column which will be used to deferentiate shifts. Optimally, this column will be populated with a text value of ShiftStartTimeDate_UnitCode_ShiftCount. The rules for my shifts are going to be that if there is a change in unit or if there is a time lapse greater than 6 hours then a new shift will begin. I'm working with very large tables so I don't want to loop over all the records. 
I want to derive the shift field in the example below:

```
|str_time        |unitcode|next_unitcode|time_diff|shift                |
|________________|________|_____________|_________|_____________________|
|2015-08-26 10:52|A       |A            |1:00     |2015-08-26 10:52_A_1 |
|2015-08-26 11:52|A       |A            |1:00     |2015-08-26 10:52_A_1 |
|2015-08-26 18:52|A       |A            |7:00     |2015-08-26 18:52_A_2 |
|2015-08-26 19:52|A       |B            |1:00     |2015-08-26 18:52_A_2 |
|2015-08-26 06:52|B       |B            |-13:00   |2015-08-26 06:52_B_1 |
|2015-08-26 10:52|B       |B            |4:00     |2015-08-26 06:52_B_1 |
|2015-08-26 11:52|B       |B            |1:00     |2015-08-26 06:52_B_1 |
|2015-08-26 12:52|B       |C            |1:00     |2015-08-26 06:52_B_1 |
|2015-08-26 14:52|C       |C            |2:00     |2015-08-26 14:52_C_1 |
|2015-08-26 22:52|C       |C            |8:00     |2015-08-26 22:52_C_2 |
|2015-08-27 02:52|C       |C            |4:00     |2015-08-26 22:52_C_2 |
|2015-08-27 09:52|C       |C            |7:00     |2015-08-27 09:52_C_3 |
|2015-08-27 10:52|C       |D            |1:00     |2015-08-27 09:52_C_3 |
|2015-08-27 11:52|D       |D            |1:00     |2015-08-27 11:52_D_1 |
|2015-08-27 12:52|D       |D            |1:00     |2015-08-27 11:52_D_1 |
```

I feel like I am getting close:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_shift()
RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    shiftInt integer;
BEGIN       
    UPDATE public.top10
        SET shift = str_time || '_' || unitcode || '_' || shiftInt, shiftInt =: (CASE
            WHEN 
                public.top10.unitcode <> public.top10.next_unitcode  
            THEN 
                0
            ELSE
                CASE
                    WHEN 
                        public.top10.time_diff >= '06:00:00'
                    THEN
                        shiftInt
                    ELSE 
                        shiftInt+1
                END
        END);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

My logic seems to work, somewhat. However, I'm having a difficult time incrementing and zeroing shiftInt variable as needed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a table representation

Comment: The function in your question references `next_unitcode` column, while a table representation doesn't have such a column. Hard to give any advice except that this code is not suposed to work because there is no `next_unitcode` in the source table.

Comment: Sorry about that. 11th hour editing always gets the best of me. I have the correct fields now.